# Junit testing in java

Tags: junit

Please, how can I write a junit test cases for these methods :

```
public void setDishProvider(DishProvider dishProvider) {
        this.dishProvider= dishProvider;
        dishProvider.addDishListener(this);
    }




public int peopleHelped() {
        return counter; //returns the counter..
    }
```

Comment: Elaborate a bit. What's the rest of the class? What do you want to verify in your test? What have you tried already?

Comment: you simply write a unit test as usual: 1. setUp preconditions, 2. call your method, 3. assert postconditions, 4. tearDown any helper stuff you needed

Comment: This question is not very good. Make sure to include in the question what you want to test. What is a DishProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guessing blindly...

```
@Test
public void testSetDishProvider() {
    YourClass yourclass = new YourClass();
    DishProvider dishProvider = new DishProvider();

    yourClass.setDishProvider(dishProvider);

    assertEquals(dishProvider, yourClass.getDishProvider());
    assertTrue(dishProvider.getListeners().contains(yourClass));
}
```